# Android studio emulator is portrait but screen is landscape?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

[image]

screen is landscape in android studio. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in the AVD Properties (that is the emulator) but I highly recommend to use your own device or Geny Motion, since it work better and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use these shortcuts to change an emulator orientation in Android Studio:

- Mac: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Windows: <kbd>left-ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Linux: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>